# img:hover transition not matching given variable

Tags: css, hover, fade

Ok so I am trying to create an inversion effect on hover of the silhouette, I've gotten all the CSS to change accordingly and used some minor JS to replace the image but the fading transition for the image goes much quicker than everything else. Even when setting the time to far more than it should be it does not seem to effecting it.

You should be able to see my style sheet at the link below, it's pretty tiny but I figured I'd let you guys see it all instead of the specific lines I'm talking about because I believe there could be a conflict.

```
#shadow {
    width:33%;
    -webkit-transition: all 2.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 2.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 2.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 2.2s ease-in-out;   
}
#shadow:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all 2.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 2.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 2.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 2.2s ease-in-out;   
}
```

Comment: Why are you including three separate versions of jQuery on one page?

Comment: Also, rather than simply posting a link to your website and asking us to inspect the source, please post relevant code samples (such as how you are triggering animations , etc) to the question itself.  It's ok to leave the link available to demo I suppose, but you don't want to permanently tie the usefulness of this question to your website.

Comment: inspecting your page with developer tools in firefox I got an error and some issues:

error  at:[22:56:41.680] Error in parsing value for '-moz-transition'  Declaration dropped. @ http://coreytegeler.com/new/css/style.css:94
  
    ` -moz-transition: all .s ease-in-out;`

issue at: (unknown property)

    `  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #DDD;`

both declaration were dropped

check that

Comment: @Anze thanks for pointing that out, just fixed it up

I've set the transitions to 2.2s as you can see in my question and it's clearly not listening

Comment: sorry but I have no idea why that's not working... rumble rumble.. did you try using -webkit-transition for something easier and obvious to check if it respects the timing? it might be a configuration file missing somewhere but I really don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working on `:hover` because you simply change source of img. CSS has nothing to do with it.

You can place `image` in a `div` and set other image as `div`'s `background-image`. Then on hover just reduce `opacity` to `0`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XdwDs/)

#### EDIT

In future you can use CSS `filter` property. Currently its supported by just `-webkit`. It'll be as simple as

```
img {
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

and you're done. But currently its just

```
img {
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);`
    /*-moz -o -ms all are unimplimented*/
}
```

[**Proof of concept**](http://jsfiddle.net/X44Ea/) (Use `chrome` or `safari` to see the effect)

[**+`filter`(W3C)**](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#FilterProperty)